# OpenCV crashing on cv.Resize

Tags: python, opencv

When running OpenCV on Windows 7, using the standard python shell, I get the following behavior.

```
import cv
im    = cv.LoadImageM("data/somefile.jpg")
thumb = cv.CreateMat(im.rows/6, im.cols/6, im.type) 

print "Before"
cv.Resize(im, thumb)
print "After"
```

Gives:

```
>>> Before
========================= RESTART ==========================
```

No error is thrown, what should I look for? What causes such crashing in OpenCV/Python?

Comment: The code works for me with OpenCV 2.2 binaries from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#opencv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to rebuild OpenCV using **Visual Studio (Express) 2010**, in stead of **MinGW**, that did the trick, so I guess it was just a faulty build in the end.

Answer (score 2):

Most memory allocation in OpenCV is unchecked and can result in crashes. OpenCV also attempts to throw exceptions through C code, which may cause anything to happen (usually a crash) depending on how it was compiled.

Check whether the values of `im.rows/6`, etc. are what you expect and that the image sizes should be within python memory limits.

Answer (score 0):

i don't think your program is crashing,it is doing just what you are telling it to do.
See the codes below,am using openCv 2.2 with python 2.7.2.Try using WaitKey() to prevent crashes!

```
import cv
cv.NamedWindow("win",cv.CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE)
im= cv.LoadImageM("image.jpg")
thumb= cv.CreateMat(im.rows/3, im.cols/3, im.type) 
cv.Resize(im, thumb)
cv.ShowImage("win",thumb)
cv.WaitKey(10000)
```

Comment: It should have at least printed the line "After", no?